# Implement SlideGroup as part of Form [DevExpress]

Tags: winforms, microsoft-metro, devexpress

I would like the Windows UI style SlideGroup on my WinForms page but dont want to go through the nonsense of having a document manager taking up my whole form. I simply want a few buttons at the top of my form and then a slideGroup at the bottom. On button press switch the slideview to the corresponding document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the [SlideGroup](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010ViewsWindowsUISlideGrouptopic) is available only as a [content container](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11771) within [WindowsUIView](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11358), which is a part of the [DocumentManager](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11359) component. Content containers can be easyly added in the related section of the [WindowsUIView Designer](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11768). The SlideGroup component is not a Control itself, thus it is impossible to use SlideGroup  without a DocumentManager.

Please also review the following: [How to create SlideGroup container](http://help.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument11795).

If you want to use the Windows UI buttons itself you can use the [WindowsUIButtonsPanel](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/clsDevExpressXtraBarsDocking2010WindowsUIButtonPaneltopic) control.